# display the latest status of user id

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display the latest users status but for some reason the output keeps displaying them all.

For example, this is my table

```
employeeid | employee  | status
123        | Don Smith | 0
123        | Don Smith | 1
```

This is what I'm trying to get; the latest Don Smith Status

```
employeeid | employee  | status
123        | Don Smith | 1


SELECT spe1.employeeid, spe1.employee, spe1.status 
FROM sp_employees spe1 
WHERE spe1.employeeid = (SELECT spe2.employeeid
                     FROM sp_employees spe2
                     WHERE spe1.employeeid = spe2.employeeid           
                     ORDER BY spe2.employeeid DESC
                     LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: MySQL isn't going to be able to distinguish which row is "latest" in the set. Without an ORDER BY, a MIN() or MAX() aggregate, there is no concept of "order" in the resultset. MySQL can return any row that satisfies the predicate. The row will to need to contain information which MySQL can use to make the determination whether it is the "latest" row or not. As an example, the addition of a DATETIME column, which can then be used to order the rows.

Comment: It's not "too broad". It's insoluble - but until they have a button for that...

Answer (score 1):

The `employeeid` is equal in both entries, your query selects all the users with this employeeid  which in this case = all users.

First, you have to keep the id unique. You can also use `distinct` to avoid repetitions of the same user.

Note that your `LIMIT 1` only applies on the inner query which returns the requested `employeeid`.

Also, if you want to change the status of the user, use an `UPDATE` query that will update the status value, instead of adding a new entry to the table.

Comment: Could you please help and provide me an example with using distinct using my first table. Because you're right, I want to avoid showing the same user as I'm just trying to get the latest status of the employee. For example, a single user could have 10 entries all with the same status 0 so I want to show that, when the user status changes to 1, then I want to display the 1, then when a user status changes to 0, the 0 will be displayed. Make sense?